# how to remove previous text when user enter a new number or character and start typing in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a textbox ,i want whenever user start entering a number in that texbox the previous value should be remove.

Let say there is a textbox which contain a number as 23 ,i want whenever user start typing in that same textbox 23 shold be remove and new enetered number should be shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `select` function on [text `input`s](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/textFieldSelection.html#dom-textarea/input-select) and [`textarea`s](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/textFieldSelection.html#dom-textarea/input-select) to select all of the text. Then when the user types, the text gets replaced.

For example, if the `input` or `textarea` has the `id` `"target"`:

```
document.getElementById("target").select();
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/umageq/1/) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/umageq/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do something like this

```
<input type="text" onclick="clear(this);">
```

And then make the javascript function named clear (or whatever name you want)

```
<javascript type="text/javascript">

function clear(element)
{
    element.value = "";
}

</script>
```

Comment: You can also use onblur instead of onclick if you want to call the function when you enter something in the input field, instead of when you click on it.